# Issue with generic types of ArrayList and interface inheritance

Tags: java, generics, collections, types, subclass

I'm having trouble understanding why the following doesn't work and I'm sure the answer is related to something basic I am not understanding and hope someone can help.

I understand about using interfaces in an `ArrayList` such that if I have:

```
public interface Weapon { ... }
public class Gun implements Weapon { ...}
public class Knife implements Weapon { ... }
```

you can then insert anything that implements Weapon into the an array of weapons:

```
ArrayList<Weapon> weapons = new ArrayList<Weapon>();
weapons.add(new Gun());
weapons.add(new Knife();
```

I get that, but what is confusing me is the understanding of why `ArrayList<Gun>` isn't compatible with `ArrayList<Weapon>` in other ways. To illustrate, the following is legal:

```
public void interfaceIsTheArgument(Weapon w) { ... }
...
interfaceIsTheArgument(new Gun());
interfaceIsTheArgument(new Knife());
```

but the following is not:

```
public void interfaceIsTheArgument(ArrayList<Weapon> w) { ... }
...
interfaceIsTheArgument(new ArrayList<Gun>());
interfaceIsTheArgument(new ArrayList<Knife>());
```

because the last function call reports that the method isn't applicable for its arguments.

My question is why if the method knows it tasks an `ArrayList` with an interface as the generic type, why isn't it okay to pass in an array list of knives in that last statement?

Comment: I don't know the exact answer, but what you can do for your second example is use `public void interfaceIsTheArgument(ArrayList<? extends Weapon>)`. That will work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To "fix" the code, you need to use a generic *bound*:

```
public void interfaceIsTheArgument(List<? extends Weapon> w) { ... }
...
interfaceIsTheArgument(new ArrayList<? extends Weapon> ());
interfaceIsTheArgument(new ArrayList<Knife>());
```

The key reason is `List<Gun>` is **not** a subclass of `List<Weapon>`. The reason for this fact can be illustrated by this code:

```
List<Gun> guns = new ArrayList<Gun>();
// If List<Weapon> was a super type of List<Gun>, this next line would be allowed
List<Weapon> weapons = guns; // Won't compile, but let's assume it did
weapons.add(new Knife());  // Compiles, because Knife is a Weapon
Gun gun = guns.get(0); // Oops! guns.get(0) is a Knife, not a Gun!
```

By using the bound `<? extends Weapon>`, we are saying we'll accept any generic type that is a *subclass* of `Weapon`. Using bounds can be very powerful. This kind of bound is an *upper* bound - we are specifying the top-level class as being `Weapon`.

There's also a *lower* bound, that uses this syntax:

```
List<? super Weapon> // accept any type that is a Weapon or higher in the class hierarchy
```

So, when to use each one? Remember this word `PECS`: "Producer extends, consumer super". This means on the producer side of the code (where the objects are *created*) use `extends`, and on the consumer side of the code (where the objects are *used*) us `super`. Once you try it a few times, you'll understand through experience why it works well.

[This SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs) covers it well.

Answer (score 4):

This is one of the most asked questions about generics. It a `List<Gun>` was a `List<Weapon>`, you could do

```
List<Gun> gunList = new ArrayList<Gun>();
List<Weapon> weaponList = gunList;
weaponList.add(new Knife());
gunList.get(0).fire(); // ClassCastException
```

This would thus break the type-safety promised by generics.